# async code in forEach loop nodejs

Tags: database, node.js, asynchronous, io

I have been trying to write some code that writes rows to my database. it:

- takes an `offer` object (dependency)
- reads from the offer object an `items` array through a callback (dependency)
- iterates each item
- takes some values from the `offer` and `item` objects
- reads from db some statistical data to determine the item's value
- writes above two line's fields to an array
- pushes the array to an array of arrays
- uses this array to insert rows into db

```js
function WriteToDB(object) {
  object.getItems(function (err, items) {
  var rowlist = [];
  items.forEach(function (item) {
    var field1 = offer.name;
    var field2 = item.name;
    var field3 = getItemValue(item.name); //async db call
    var row = [field1, field2, field3];
    rowlist.push(row);
  });

  write(valuelist);
}
```

i know this wont work, but i can't seem to *grok* nodejs enough to figure out how to solve this simple to be done task in other languages. I messed with learning `async.waterfall`, but got confused because there's a synchronous foreach loop mixed in the chain of otherwise pretty asynchronous stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use async module, like:

```
var async = require('async');

function WriteToDB(object) {

    object.getItems(function (err, items) {
        var rowlist = [];

        async.each(items, function (item, cb) {
            var field1 = offer.name;
            var field2 = item.name;
            getItemValue(item.name, function (value) {
                var field3 = value;
                var row = [field1, field2, field3];
                rowlist.push(row);
                cb();
            }); //async db call

        }, function () {

            // All async read are completed here
            write(rowlist);
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library i just created called `utils-pkg` which has a function called `.each()` that iterates each element from an object or array. It is not synchronous but with the callback you can continue to next iteration when asked

Also the function has another callback parameter which is executed once all the iterations are done

Check the package [here](https://github.com/Nosthertus/node-utils-pkg)

```
var utils = require("utils-pkg");

function WriteToDB(object) {
    object.getItems(function (err, items) {
        var rowlist = [];

        utils.each(items, function(index, value, next){
            var field1 = offer.name;
            var field2 = value.name;
            var field3 = getItemValue(value.name); //async db call
            var row = [field1, field2, field3];

            rowlist.push(row);
            next();  // call this once you are done with this iteration
        }, function(){
            // This is called when all iterations are done
            write(valuelist);
        });
    });
}
```